# Maven generate jar dependencies then war

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I'm using m2e Maven Plugin for Eclipse. I'm having 5 eclipse projects. A web application project and then 4 projects as jars dependencies for my web application.

I would like to know how can I package jars before including them in the WAR using "mvn clean install" on war project.

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>dispatcher</groupId>
<artifactId>dispatcher</artifactId>
<version>4.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>referentiel</groupId>
        <artifactId>referentiel</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mailTemplates</groupId>
        <artifactId>mailTemplates</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>qualityTool</groupId>
        <artifactId>qualityTool</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
    ..
    .
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please look at my post for more details!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of @Jigar Joshi is good but i thing you need a view of structure which can help you to understand quickly what we mean.

I. Create a top level maven module (parent of war and jars)
You habe already the 5 moduls that you need. Now create a new Maven project as parent which must contain only a pom.xml file.

**parent project pom**

```
 <project...>               
            <groupId>groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <name>Define parent pom </name>
      <!-- modul -->
  <project>
```

II. Put your jar projects first as modul and at the end the war project. If you have another dependencies in the jar projects you may also try to order them consequently.

**parent project pom**

```
 <modules>
        <module>referentiel</module> <!-- jar -->
        <module>mailTemplates</module> <!-- jar -->
        <module>qualityTool</module> <!-- jar -->
        <module>tools</module> <!-- jar -->
        <module>dispatcher</module> <!-- war-->
    </modules>
```

III. in all other project put the parent reference into the poms

```
   <parent>
       <groupId>groupId</groupId>
       <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
```

IV. Now you can go to inside the new created parent project and run from there

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: I'm having the same structure but still having that 

`[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find dispatcher:dispatcherParent:pom:4.7 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, column 10 -> [Help 2]`

Comment: <relativePath>../Dispatcher/pom.xml</relativePath> in <parent> solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Either create a top level maven module (parent of war and jars) and execute `mvn clean install`

```
---pom.xml
   |
   |dispatcher---pom.xml (war)
   |qualityTool----pom.xml (jar)
   |mailTemplates----pom.xml (jar)
   |referentiel----pom.xml (jar)
   |tools----pom.xml (jar)
```

or use [`--also-make`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) command line option to make dependencies as well

Comment: Maybe you meant not *parent*, but *reactor* module/pom? Parent shares common plugins/dependencies, while reactor simply triggers `<modules>`.

Comment: yes creating a module which act as father of war and jars and building it, if OP wants custom build s/he can go for custom build profile tied at parent module

Comment: I tried the parent/modules structure as Jigar and Festus suggested but I'm having this error now when trying "mvn clean install" :
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 5 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: `[ERROR]   The project PacificaIntegrateurReferentiel:PacificaIntegrateurReferentiel:4.7 (C:\Users\melbakkali\workspace_kepler\referentiel\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find Dispatcher:Dispatcher:pom:4.7 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 17, column 10 ->`

Comment: see the directory ascii structure and poms, also see how to declare `<modules>` and `<parent>`

Comment: well adding this to parents tags solved it `<relativePath>../Dispatcher/pom.xml</relativePath>`