# Using maven to build ear project

Tags: java, maven, ear

Usually `EAR` has many `package(war, jar, ejb)` , added to the deployment assembly, if i want to convert such project to `maven` project what do i do?
is it right to clear the deployment assembly and add those package as `dependency`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use maven to build your ear file so you have to follow maven documentation to know the process.

I hope that you have already some informations about maven!?

1. If you are using Eclipse as IDE you have to install maven plugin (me2) if until now you don't have it.
2. From now you have the possibility to transform your project into maven project by selecting your project and right click and `configure` and chose `convert to maven project`.
3. Look at [maven-generate-jar-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606001/maven-generate-jar-dependencies-then-war/20606226#20606226) with my answer to see how you can manage them together